# Perl using USAePay billing module

Tags: perl

I was wondering if anybody has experience using the USAePay billing module?  I have reached out to the developer and his response was he does not have time to help people.  My problem is this -

I have written the following code to add a customer's billing information using the Sandbox server but it looks as though the module defaults to the production server so each time I attempt to validate the transaction I get the response -

> Card was rejected: Specified source key not found.

How do I tell it to use the Sandbox server?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Business::OnlinePayment;

use constant {
    LOGIN         => 'source key',  #USAePay source key
    PASSWORD      => '12345',       #USAePay PIN
};

my $tx = new Business::OnlinePayment("USAePay");
$tx->content(
    login           => LOGIN,
    password        => PASSWORD,
    type            => 'CC',
    action          => 'Recurring Authorization',
    description     => 'Business::OnlinePayment test',
    amount          => '49.95',
    invoice_number  => '100100',
    name            => 'Tofu Beast',
    card_number     => '4000100011112224',
    expiration      => '09/19',
    address         => '1234 Bean Curd Lane',
    city            => 'San Francisco',
    state           => 'CA',
    zip             => '94102',
);
$tx->submit();

if($tx->is_success()) {
    print 'Card processed successfully: '.$tx->authorization.'\n';
} else {
    print 'Card was rejected: '.$tx->error_message."\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the module's code?

Comment: You could also take a look at their Perl API page so see whether you can find the issue with the module (perhaps its just a documentation thing that the code can show you) or use their examples: https://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Business::OnlinePayment::USAePay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::OnlinePayment::USAePay) is a *processor* for [Business::OnlinePayment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::OnlinePayment), but doesn't have a lot of docs itself, a  look at the docs of Business::OnlinePayment might help. It reveales [the `test_transaction` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::OnlinePayment#test_transaction).

> Most processors provide a test mode, where submitted transactions will not actually be charged or added to your batch, calling this function with a true argument will turn that mode on if the processor supports it, or generate a fatal error if the processor does not support a test mode (which is probably better than accidentally making real charges).

An untested example:

```
my $tx = new Business::OnlinePayment("USAePay");
$tx->test_transaction; # here
$tx->content(
    login           => LOGIN,
    password        => PASSWORD,
    type            => 'CC',
    action          => 'Recurring Authorization',
    description     => 'Business::OnlinePayment test',
    amount          => '49.95',
    invoice_number  => '100100',
    name            => 'Tofu Beast',
    card_number     => '4000100011112224',
    expiration      => '09/19',
    address         => '1234 Bean Curd Lane',
    city            => 'San Francisco',
    state           => 'CA',
    zip             => '94102',
);
$tx->submit();
```

Digging a bit deeper in the [source of  Business::OnlinePayment::USAePay shows](https://metacpan.org/source/IVAN/Business-OnlinePayment-USAePay-0.03/USAePay.pm#L158) that this particular *processor* actually has three different test modes.

> ```
>  # test_transaction(0): normal mode
>     #                  1 : test mode (validates formatting only)
>     #                  2 : use sandbox server
>     #                  3 : test mode on sandbox server
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](http://search.cpan.org/~ivan/Business-OnlinePayment-3.03/OnlinePayment.pm#new%28$processor,_%25processor_options%29) you can set the server details in the constructor - it takes an optional hash of parameters beyond the processor name.

Have you tried something like:

```
my $tx = new Business::OnlinePayment(
  "USAePay",
  Server => 'https://sandbox.usaepay.com/gate'
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag! This is a good first answer, and a good idea. :)

Comment: Although it's not clear if B::OP::USAePay actually supports that option. The code doesn't look like it unfortunately. Seems like it just sets defaults with no way to overwrite them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Unfortunately I didn't have time to dig into the USAePay module code at the time of writing - and wrote my response while you were elaborating on yours.  Just wanted to make sure the basics were covered first of all :)